# Java fails in moving (renaming) a file when the resulting file is on another filesystem

Tags: java, linux, filesystems

A program we have erred when trying to move files from one directory to another. After much debugging I located the error by writing a small utility program that just moves a file from one directory to another (code below). It turns out that while moving files around on the local filesystem works fine, trying to move a file to another filesystem fails.

Why is this? The question might be platform specific - we are running Linux on ext3, if that matters.

And the second question; should I have been using something else than the `renameTo()` method of the `File` class? It seems as if this just works on local filesystems.

Tests (run as root):

```
touch /tmp/test/afile

java FileMover /tmp/test/afile /root/
The file move was successful

touch /tmp/test/afile

java FileMover /tmp/test/afile /some_other_disk/
The file move was erroneous
```

Code:

```
import java.io.File;

public class FileMover {
    public static void main(String arguments[] ) throws Exception {
        boolean success;
        File file = new File(arguments[0]);
        File destinationDir = new File(arguments[1]);
        File destinationFile = new File(destinationDir,file.getName() );
        success = file.renameTo(destinationFile);
        System.out.println("The file move was " + (success?"successful":"erroneous"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Java 7 and above

Use [`Files.move(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... opts)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)).

Note that you must not provide the `ATOMIC_MOVE` option when moving files between file systems.

### Java 6 and below

From the docs of [`File.renameTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29):

> [...] *The rename operation might not be able to move a file from one filesystem to another* [...]

The obvious workaround would be to copy the file "manually" by opening a new file, write the content to the file, and delete the old file.

You could also try the [`FileUtils.moveFile`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) method from Apache Commons.

Comment: Errr... didnt load your answer while I composed mine :), moveFile is the savior +1

Comment: Your suggestion on Apache Commons was exactly my next step. Thanks for an informative answer that actually answers both questions!

Comment: To add to the excellent answer already provided above, the system call used in renaming returns EXDEV if oldpath and newpath are not on the same mounted file system. In fact program such as "mv" handle this situation by doing an explicit copy followed by delete operation.

Comment: Starting with java 7 you can use java.nio.file.Files.move which can handle different filesystems, you must not use the ATOMIC_MOVE option, though.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)

Answer (score 6):

[Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) to the rescue:

> Many aspects of the behavior of this method are inherently
>   platform-dependent: The rename operation might not be able to move a
>   file from one filesystem to another, it might not be atomic, and it
>   might not succeed if a file with the destination abstract pathname
>   already exists. The return value should always be checked to make sure
>   that the rename operation was successful.
>
> Note that the Files class defines the move method to move or rename a
>   file in a platform independent manner.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> Renames the file denoted by this abstract pathname.
>
> Many aspects of the behavior of this method are inherently
>   platform-dependent: The rename operation might not be able to move a
>   file from one filesystem to another, it might not be atomic, and it
>   might not succeed if a file with the destination abstract pathname
>   already exists. The return value should always be checked to make sure
>   that the rename operation was successful.

If you want to move file between different file system you can use Apache's [moveFile](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#moveFile%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29)

Answer (score -1):

your ider is error 
beause /some_other_disk/ is relative url but completely url ,can not find the url 
i have example

java FileMover D:\Eclipse33_workspace_j2ee\test\src\a\a.txt D:\Eclipse33_workspace_j2ee\test\src
The file move was successful

java FileMover D:\Eclipse33_workspace_j2ee\test\src\a\a.txt  \Eclipse33_workspace_j2ee\test\src

The file move was erronous

result is url is error

Comment: any path starting with '/' is an absolute path (on unices). So no. see the answers above for something that actually answers the question.